# EmberJS Helper to dynamically call components

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a model which have a relationship with several type of model inside the same property (folder: subfolder and item).

I wonder how to render children of the model without using

```
{{#if item.isFolder}}
    {{#folder-item folder=item parent=this}}{{/folder-item}}
{{/if}}

{{#if item.isPage}}
    {{#page-item page=item parent=this}}{{/page-item}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Use the `component` helper: `{{#component item.componentName key1=value1 key2=value2}}...{{/component}}`

Comment: cool Thanks :) Please add an answer so I can mark this question as resolved.

Comment: Resolved as duplicate ^^ Doesn't matter, I had just dropped a line as a quick hint before I had to go, took me 15s.